# How to activate an autocomplete for my own libraries in PyCharm?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm used to a very convenient autocomplete in PyCharm and hints about a parameter info (by pressing Ctrl+P). But anything of these doesn't work for my own library. For example, in the program script.py doesn't work neither  autocomplete nor parameter info:

**./libs/mylib.py**

```
def PrintMe(TextToPrint):
    print TextToPrint
```

**script.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./libs')
import mylib

mylib.P[No autocomplete, no hints, no pop-up window with list of functions]
```

How can I "teach" PyCharm to my libraries?  PyCharm 3.4.1; python 2.7.3

Comment: It could be because it's not directly importable by the Python interpreter; could you change things to remove the need for `sys.path.append`?

Comment: You are right, but without `sys.path.append` I have to store all library in script's folder. But I have a directory with my libraries and would like to import library from specific directory. Is it another way to import library from specific folder?

Comment: You could write a `setup.py` and actually *install* the library in your project's interpreter/virtualenv. Also, note that it's backticks `\`` for code formatting, not `$`.